# Screen scraping a page with .exe href links

Tags: curl, screen-scraping

Using curl I am attempting to harvest real-time water flow data from the following webpage: https://www.waterrights.utah.gov/cgi-bin/dvrtview.exe?Modinfo=Collection_Sysview&SYSTEM_NAME=BEAVER%20RIVER

Using:

bret@ubuntu:~$ curl https://www.waterrights.utah.gov/cgi-bin/dvrtview.exe?Modinfo=Collection_Sysview&SYSTEM_NAME=BEAVER%20RIVER

returns no flow values. I suspect this has something to do with the data being generated by a call to a database on the webserver via the executable dvrtview.exe.

Am wondering if curl needs to be passed a command line switch. I have also attempted to use headless chromium with the same result.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Data is there when I run that cURL command.

Comment: My fault @Quentin. I had not quoted URL

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the URL solved the problem:

curl 'https://www.waterrights.utah.gov/cgi-bin/dvrtview.exe?Modinfo=Collection_Sysview&SYSTEM_NAME=BEAVER%20RIVER'